# What is the equivalent of a MUL key in PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have been researching MUL keys within MySQL, to my understanding this key allows multiple occurrences of a given value. Non-unique to me means that this value can occur more than once within the column.

1). Is my understanding of this correct

2). Is it necessary to replicate MUL keys within PostgreSQL

If the answer to question to is yes, then...

3). How do you create a MUL key in PostgreSQL

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Gordon's answer I learned about this MySQL *feature*. PostgreSQL (fortunately, must I add) doesn't have it.

To recap about your questions:

> 1). Is my understanding of this correct

Yes, your understanding is correct in MySQL lingo. However, it's important to understand that in the relational database world the concept of "key" implies uniqueness. In MySQL, however, it's synonym of "index" (unique and non-unique). In this case `MUL` means: non-unique index.

> 2). Is it necessary to replicate MUL keys within PostgreSQL

PostgreSQL has indexes, unique an non-unique ones. They cover the same ground as MySQL's "keys", except for the extra feature of "exporting foreign keys" that I consider sketchy at best; PostgrSQL doesn't allow them. Better to stay away from them, anyway.

> If the answer to question to is yes, then...

The answer is "yes" with the caveat mentioned above.

> 3). How do you create a MUL key in PostgreSQL

Just create a simple index. For example:

```
create index ix1 on my_table (my_column);
```

You can include multiple columns in the index, separated by commas. It non-unique by default.

**Why would I stay away from Non-Unique Exported Foreign Keys?**

Why exporting non-unique keys could be a problem, you may ask? See this example:

```
create table t (a int, b int);

create index ix1 on t (a);

insert into t (a, b) values (null, 1), (123, 2), (456, 3), (456, 4);

create table u (
  c int,
  constraint fk1 foreign key (c) references t (a) on update cascade
);

-- the statement above makes column "a" an Exported Foreign Key.    

insert into u (c) values (null), (123), (456);

-- row 456 in table u, points to two rows (3 and 4) in table t.

update t set a = a + 1 where b = 4;

-- after updating, row 456 in table u, points to a single row in t
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/seVdFp6eZaFMef7jg7ea8X/0).

In this example you can verify that the foreign key relationship ends up broken after a single `UPDATE`.

Comment: Note: there is also the problem of NULLs being allowed in indexes, but not in fields of (composite) keys. Which makes perfectly sense.

Answer (score 2):

A MUL key simply means that the key is part of an index (well, a non-unique index) in MySQL.

There is nothing special about such a key.  In both databases, you can create such an index using `CREATE INDEX`.  You should not use such keys for foreign key constraints, although MySQL seems to violate standard SQL by allowing that.

Comment: Holy guacamole. A foreign key can point to a key... that is not unique... interesting. You learn something new every day.

Comment: @TheImpaler Recebtly , I *learned* that the `ON` clause on a `JOIN` is **optional** in mysql, Omitting it leads to a Cathesian product!

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . Only in MySQL (as far as I know).